# Writing into text file from ArrayList that has multiple values per ArrayList object (java)

Tags: java, arraylist, text-files, bufferedreader, filewriter

I am trying to save my ArrayList into a text file. But the format of how it is saved is wrong. My code:

```
ArrayList<Vehicle> vehs = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();

vehs.add(new Vehicle("QJT123", "Starlet 99", 35.0, 190000));
vehs.add(new PremiumVehicle("TUX132", "BWM 05  ", 90.0, 12000, 100, 10000, 5000));
```

Constructor used for these 2:

```
public PremiumVehicle(String vehicleID, String description, double dailyRate, int odometer, int allowance, int serLength, int lastOdo) //subclass

public Vehicle(String vehicleID, String description, double dailyRate, int odometer) //Superclass
```

Both of these are stored into the Vehicle ArrayList. Code to save to text file:

```
private static void saveFile(ArrayList<Vehicle> vehs){
    File fileName = new File("VehicleList.txt");        

    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName);
        Writer output = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        for (int i = 0; i < vehs.size(); i++){
            output.write(vehs.get(i).toString() + "\n");
        }

        output.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I cannot create that file");
    }
}
```

My output in VehicleList.txt:

```
vehicle ID = QJT123 Description = Starlet 99    Status = A  Daily Rate = 35.0 Odometer reading = 190000vehicle ID = TUX132  Description = BWM 05    Status = A  Daily Rate = 90.0   Odometer reading = 12000 Mileage allowance = 100    service length = 10000  Last Service = 5000
```

How do i make it such that each new line is added when writing in a new ArrayList object, e.g:

```
vehicle ID = QJT123 Description = Starlet 99    Status = A  Daily Rate = 35.0 Odometer reading = 190000
vehicle ID = TUX132 Description = BWM 05    Status = A  Daily Rate = 90.0   Odometer reading = 12000 Mileage allowance = 100    service length = 10000  Last Service = 5000
```

I've tried using `vehs.get(i).toString() + "\n"` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: not clear for me, your 2 objects are getting written in the same line???

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ yes, in my text file, it is all written in one line. A new line is suppose to be added right before vehicle ID

Comment: doesn't make any sense. tested with some code and it works perfectly fine

Comment: are you running that on something else as windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) has a `newLine()` method, you may use that if you declare `output` as a `BufferedWriter` .

```
private static void saveFile(ArrayList<Vehicle> vehs){
    File fileName = new File("VehicleList.txt"); 


    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName);
        BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        for (int i = 0; i < vehs.size(); i++){
            output.write(vehs.get(i).toString());
            output.newLine();
        }

        output.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I cannot create that file");
    }
}
```

Also for the javadoc of the method :

> Writes a line separator. The line separator string is defined by the
>   system property line.separator, and is not necessarily a single
>   newline ('\n') character.

Comment: `\n` should work in his code. at least it does for me

Comment: It is platform-dependent .

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yeah.. somehow \n isn't working for me.

Comment: @Berger with `\n\r` it should work on every common OS right?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer : well indeed with `\r\n` it should match the common system's new line sequences (`\r\n`, `\r`, `\n` ) .

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, your platform does not see \n as a newline character - that thing depends on the OS.

One way to obtain the correct newline marker:

```
String lineSep = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

or even simpler:

```
String lineSep = System.lineSeparator();
```

and instead of using `+ "\n"` you do `+ lineSep` in your code.

Comment: or even better ***System.lineSeparator()***